# Pandas - Replace values based on index

Tags: python, numpy, pandas, replace, dataframe

If I create a dataframe like so:

```
import pandas as pd, numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0,100,size=(100, 2)), columns=list('AB'))
```

How would I change the entry in column A to be the number 16 from row 0 -15, for example? In other words, how do I replace cells based purely on index?

Answer (score 88, accepted):

Use [`loc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html):

```
df.loc[0:15,'A'] = 16
print (df)
     A   B
0   16  45
1   16   5
2   16  97
3   16  58
4   16  26
5   16  87
6   16  51
7   16  17
8   16  39
9   16  73
10  16  94
11  16  69
12  16  57
13  16  24
14  16  43
15  16  77
16  41   0
17   3  21
18   0  98
19  45  39
20  66  62
21   8  53
22  69  47
23  48  53
```

Solution with `ix` is [deprecated](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#ix-indexer-is-deprecated).

Comment: This now gives a FutureWarning: Slicing a positional slice with .loc is not supported. df.A.iloc[0:15] = 16 should still work.

Answer (score 31):

In addition to the other answers, here is what you can do if you have a **list of individual indices**:

```
indices = [0,1,3,6,10,15]
df.loc[indices,'A'] = 16

print(df.head(16))
```

Output:

```
     A  B
0   16  4
1   16  4
2    4  3
3   16  4
4    1  1
5    3  0
6   16  4
7    2  1
8    4  4
9    3  4
10  16  0
11   3  1
12   4  2
13   2  2
14   2  1
15  16  1
```

Answer (score 8):

Very interesting observation, that code below **does** change the value in the original dataframe

```
df.loc[0:15,'A'] = 16
```

But if you use a pretty similar code like this

```
df.loc[0:15]['A'] = 16
```

Than it will give back just a **copy** of your dataframe with changed value and **doesn't** change the value in the original *df* object.
Hope that this will save some time for someone dealing with this issue.

Comment: This is called "chained assignment" and the pandas documentation recommends against it (https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html)

Answer (score 6):

One more solution is

```
df.at[0:15, 'A']=16

print(df.head(20))
```

**OUTPUT**:

```
     A   B
0   16  44
1   16  86
2   16  97
3   16  79
4   16  94
5   16  24
6   16  88
7   16  43
8   16  64
9   16  39
10  16  84
11  16  42
12  16   8
13  16  72
14  16  23
15  16  28
16  18  11
17  76  15
18  12  38
19  91   6
```

Answer (score 0):

Could you instead of 16, update the value of that column to -1.0? for me, it returns 255 instead of -1.0.

```
>>> effect_df.loc[3:5, ['city_SF', 'city_Seattle']] = -1.0

    Rent  city_SF  city_Seattle
0  3999        1             0
1  4000        1             0
2  4001        1             0
3  3499      255           255
4  3500      255           255
5  3501      255           255
6  2499        0             1
7  2500        0             1
8  2501        0             1
```

Answer (score 0):

To Mad Physicist: it appears that at first you need to change the column data types from short integer to float. Looks like your -1.0 was cast as short integer.